# Use DDMS to push the sqlite database file faild

Tags: android

i did not find my package name folder in the data/data.

There just are many folder named com

And then i try to push my sqlite database to data/data/com, But faild. 
Why?
Pls help me .

Can give me a smaple? How to use  already exist sqlite database.

I have learned from a blog : http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

But it's not use. I run the createDataBase method in the oncreat.

It's give the error message: No such table

Someone told me i need push the sqlite database to emulator first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i did not find my package name folder
>   in the data/data

Then your application is not installed. Your application's local file store (`/data/data/your.package.goes.here`) is created when your application is installed.

Note that the database subdirectory may not be created automatically -- you may have to create it using `mkdir()`. This is mentioned in one of the comments of the blog post you linked to.